# How to route / pipe output of Watson text to speech to local speaker vs terminal

Tags: raspberry-pi, watson-conversation, watson-iot

I'm using the Watson service speech to text and text to speech. So far, I've been able to get everything working excepting getting the sound to output to the speakers on a Raspberry PI running Node JS.

I'm connecting to the text to speech service. It seems that I am getting a response back from the Watson service, but it is displaying on the Pi terminal versus going to the USB speaker. At the end of the text display, it shows that it is being sent to the hw device 0:0 which is wrong.  It should go to 1:0

When I test the Raspberry Pi sound without Watson, the audio works fine without the Watson Service, using aplay which plays back on a different hw device (1:0).

So my question is this: Is there a parameter using the https: interface that enables you to control to which hw sound device to route the speech to or does that all have to be controlled locally, somewhere within my JS code.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the hw device setting of device 0:0 was coded within the js code (which I did not write).  Changing this parameter routed the sound to the correct sound card which was a usb device running on 1:0.

Mystery solved!